# Django turning off autoescape when it comes to template tags

Tags: django, forms, templates, tags, admin

so, I'm trying to write an admin form such that the admin can write html code as an input. So for this I use {% autoescape off %} to let the form bypass html code. Now, I want to have the admin have the freedom to use template tags in the entries. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing to do with autoescape, which is to do with HTML tags only. Whether it was on or off, it still wouldn't parse template tags in the variable text.

For this you'd have to write your own code to load and render the text as a template. This could be in your own template tag, for example.